# Show an $\arctan$ and $\arcsin$ function is constant

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, alternative-proof

Show that for every $x\geq1$ the following is true:
$2\arctan x + \arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^2} = \pi$

One way (mentioned in the link at the bottom) would be to calculate the derivative of the left side, show that it is always $0$ then show that for $x=1$ the equation is true.
I'm trying for some time to find a cleaner way to prove the equality, without so much algebra. Does anyone have any idea where to start?

Someone already mentioned the same problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/773192/prove-that-2-arctan-x-arcsin-frac2x1x2-pi-for-every-x-geq1).

Comment: If you show the derivative (the CHANGE in it as you go along) is 0 - that is IT NEVER CHANGES. then find its value at a point where it never changes, you know that at all points it doesn't change at around that point - that it hasn't changed.... whoa that makes it sound way more complex than it really is.

Comment: BTW I say that because there's rarely a cleaner way.

Comment: Thank you, I'm aware the problem can be solved in that way. I'm trying to find an alternative proof.

Comment: Be aware of my wishing you good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved using basic [Inverse Trigonometric Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

$$2\arctan(x) + \arcsin{\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}} $$

$$\Rightarrow \arctan\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} + \arctan\dfrac{2x}{x^2-1}$$

$$\Rightarrow \arctan\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2} + \arctan\dfrac{-2x}{1-x^2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \arctan\dfrac{0}{1+\Big(\dfrac{2x}{1-x^2}\Big)^2}$$

> Now since $x\geq 1$
>
> $$ \Rightarrow \arctan(0) = \pi$$

---

I guess you can also use [Andre Nicolas'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1321376/134694) answer as a hint!

Comment: Use the Wikipedia link I gave...

Answer (score 4):

Outline: We can do it with just trigonometric identities.  Note first that 
$$\tan(2\arctan x)=\frac{2x}{1-x^2}.\tag{1}$$
Then note that 
$$\tan\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)=\frac{2x}{x^2-1} \tag{2}$$
because $x\ge 1$. So the right-hand side of (2) is the negative of the right-hand side of (1).

No derivatives!

Answer (score 2):

We can show $\frac {2x}{1-x^2}=\tan 2 \arctan x = \tan (\pi-\arcsin \frac {2x}{1+x^2}=\tan \arcsin \frac {2x}{1+x^2})$  The left equality comes from $\tan 2y = \frac {2 \tan y}{1-\tan^2 y}$ and the second from drawing a right triangle with one angle $\arcsin \frac {2x}{1+x^2}$  As $\arctan$ is a bijection over this range, we are done.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the function

$$f(x)=2 \arctan x+\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)$$

Note that the arcsine function can be expressed alternatively as the arctangent function using $\arcsin y=\arctan \frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$ for $|y|<1$.

Here, we have $y= \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ for $|x|>1$.  Thus,

$$\arcsin \frac{2x}{1+x^2}=\arctan \frac{2x}{|1-x^2|}=\arctan \frac{2x}{x^2-1}$$

We also note that for $x>1$, $\arctan x>0$.  Therefore, we have

$$2 \arctan x=\pi+\arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}$$

since $\arctan \frac{2x}{1-x^2}<0$.

Finally, we obtain the coveted result

$2 \arctan x+\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)=\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

if $x\geq 1$, then $x=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ for some $\theta\in\left[\frac{\pi}{2},\pi\right)$, then:
$$2\arctan x + \arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2} = 2\arctan\tan\frac{\theta}{2}+\arcsin\sin\theta=\theta+(\pi-\theta)=\pi. $$

Comment: Thank you. I didn't understand this step: $\arcsin\frac{2x}{1+x^2} = \arcsin\sin\theta$ and couldn't find what identity it is based on.

Comment: @Ron: don't you know that $\sin\theta=\frac{2\tan(\theta/2)}{1+\tan^2(\theta/2)}$? It is called Weierstrass substitution, sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

i will use the letter $m$ so that i can interpret it as the slope of the radius in the init circle. let $$t = \tan^{-1}(m), m \ge 1.\tag 1$$  this implies $$\pi/4 \le t < \infty, \tan t = m, \cos t = \frac 1{\sqrt {1+m^2}}, \sin t = \frac m{\sqrt{1+m^2}}. $$  we also know from the double angle formula $$ \sin 2t = 2\sin t \cos t = \frac{2m}{1+m^2}$$ since $\pi/2 \le 2t < p,$ we have $$\sin^{-1}(\sin 2t)) = \pi - 2t.  \tag 2$$

putting $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives $$ \text{ if } 1\le m \text{ then } 2 \tan^{-1}m + \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2m}{1+m^2}\right)= \pi.$$

Answer (score 1):

> \begin{align} 2\arctan(x)+\arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)
> &=\pi
> \end{align}

Let's $\chi=\arctan(x)\ge\pi/4$ since $x\ge1$.

Consider a unit circle

[image]

Then in a $\triangle OAB$ we have $|OA|=|OB|=1$,
$\angle OAB=\angle OBA=\chi$, 
$\angle AOB=\alpha=\pi-2\chi$, 
$|AH|=\sin(\alpha)=a$.

In the $\triangle ABH$
\begin{align}
|AH|&=|BH|\tan(\chi)
\\
\sin(\alpha)
&=
(1-\cos(\alpha))\tan(\chi)
\\
\sin(\alpha)
&=
\left(1-\sqrt{1-\sin^2(\alpha)}\right)\tan(\chi)
\\
a&=
\left(1-\sqrt{1-a^2}\right)x
\\
\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)^2&=
1-a^2
\\
\frac{a^2}{x^2}+a^2 &= 2\frac{a}{x}
\\
a\left(\frac{1}{x^2}+1\right) 
&= \frac{2}{x}
\\
a&=\sin(\alpha)=
\frac{2x}{1+x^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: g.kov, What program did you use to draw your beautiful figure?

Comment: @omegadot: It's [`Asymptote`](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net)
"... a powerful descriptive vector graphics language that provides a natural coordinate-based framework for technical drawing. Labels and equations are typeset with LaTeX, for high-quality PostScript output."

Comment: Thanks g.kov for letting me know.